# Why is a double exponential function faster than $x!$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Reading [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_exponential_function) I found an interesting sentence:

> Factorials grow faster than exponential functions, but much slower than double-exponential functions.

The author doesn't provide a link let alone a proof of that fact and I don't find it obvious. After all, factorial functions grow really fast but the author says they grow *much* slower than double exponentials. Does anyone know a proof that

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{e^{x}}}{x!} = \infty$$

Comment: Google for Stirling's formula.

Comment: One can prove it without using Striling formula too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple comparison of factors shows that
$$
n!=\prod_{k=1}^nk\le\prod_{k=1}^nn =n^n\tag{1}
$$
Since
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(e^n-n\log(n)\right)
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^n\left(1-\frac{n\log(n)}{e^n}\right)\\[6pt]
&=\infty\cdot1\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
we have
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{e^n}}{n^n}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{e^n-n\log(n)}\\[6pt]
&=\infty\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Applying $(1)$ to $(3)$ gives
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{e^n}}{n!}=\infty\tag{4}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Don't need Stirling for that. It is much more basic:

Let $a_n := \frac{e^{e^n}}{n!}$. Then 
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} = \frac{e^{e^{n}e}}{e^{e^n}(n+1)} =\frac{1}{n+1}\frac{(e^{e^n})^e}{e^{e^n}} = \frac{1}{n+1}(e^{e^n})^{e-1} \geq \frac{e^{n(e-1)}}{n+1}$$
Now you only need to know that $\exp$ grows alot faster than each polynomial. This gives you that even $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ grows really fast.

Answer (score 0):

The Stirling formula gives $\ln(x!)$ is about $x \ln(x) - x$ for large $x$ so
$$
\ln\left(\frac{e^{e^x}}{x!}\right)
= e^x - \ln(x!) \approx e^x - x \ln(x) + x \to \infty
$$